# Can you say berachot in your underwear?

Tags: halacha, blessing, clothing

If for whatever reason you happen to be in your underwear (just woke up, just took a shower, etc), are you allowed to say berachot (such as asher yatzar or shehakol on water) before getting fully dressed?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think you cannot?

Comment: @DoubleAA, you're talking to the King of kings...

Comment: You mean the One Who can see through your clothes? Why should that matter?

Comment: DoubleAA well, we're not supposed to pray when naked either, even if the King's view is the same.  (@AniYodeya if that's your motivation, please edit it into the question.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This article](http://www.jewishpathways.com/files/The_Right_Environment.pdf) summarizes the rules of dress for both men and women required for saying brachot. There are footnotes to sources, as well. Excerpts:

> Another aspect of “holiness” when saying a bracha is that a man is
> required to have a “separation between his heart and his lower body.”
> This typically requires no special attention, as **it is accomplished by
> wearing a belt, pants or underwear**. However, if a man is at home
> wearing just a bathrobe, he would need to tie the robe’s belt, in
> order to create a separation between the heart and lower body.

Although, not directly addressing your question, I've included the next paragraph for general interest. If it's unuseful, comment or you may edit my answer and delete it.

> It
> is improper to say a bracha with one’s top half uncovered, unless
> there is no realistic option. Joe is sitting at the beach in his
> bathing suit and wants to say a bracha on a nice cold drink. This is
> permitted, since his private parts are covered by a bathing suit,
> which also acts as a separation “between his heart and lower body.” If
> possible, Joe should use a towel or t-shirt to also cover his upper
> half.

While the 2nd quote discusses the bracha aspect, if you were sitting on a public beach this way, you're prob. not dressed *tzniut*ly, anyway, so I would recommend waiting to make a bracha until you are.

Comment: Seems like boxers and a t-shirt suffice...

Comment: Your first block quotation addresses the necessity of underwear; your second addresses its sufficiency, which is what was asked about. I don't know why you say the second may be irrelevant. I think the first is.